# On Firebase deploy in VSCode, multiple errors in node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Basically what the title says. I'm trying to deploy cloud functions to Firebase using Typescript and I get 25 errors in node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts

I have not touched this file and I have no idea what it is. I have deployed many times in the past with no issue, so I'm assuming this must be due to some kind of update.

The only reference to this issue I have found so far is here:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/5138

This is exactly my problem, but I have updated Typescript and the issue persists. Can anyone suggest something else to try?

In case it helps, here are the error messages:

> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:125 - error
> TS1110: Type expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
> ~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:138 - error
> TS1005: '}' expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
> ~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:142 - error
> TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:180 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
>
> ```
> ~
> ```
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:181 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
>
> ```
>  ~
> ```
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:188 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
>
> ```
>         ~~~~
> ```
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:194 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
>
> ```
>               ~
> ```
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:198 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
>
> ```
>                   ~
> ```
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:6:205 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 6 export declare type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
> string extends S ? string[] : S extends "" ? [] : S extends
> `${D}${infer Tail}` ? [...Split<Tail, D>] : S extends `${infer Head}${D}${infer Tail}` ? string extends Head ? [...Split<Tail, D>] :
> [Head, ...Split<Tail, D>] : [
>
> ```
>                          ~~~~
> ```
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:66 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:68 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:75 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:81 - error
> TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:82 - error
> TS1109: Expression expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:84 - error
> TS1109: Expression expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:111 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:113 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:120 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~~~~~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:126 - error
> TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:127 - error
> TS1109: Expression expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:128 - error
> TS1109: Expression expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:155 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:21:157 - error
> TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 21 export declare type Extract = Part extends
> `{${infer Param}=**}` ? Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}=*}` ?
> Param : Part extends `{${infer Param}}` ? Param : never;
> ~
>
> node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/params.d.ts:33:1 - error
> TS1160: Unterminated template literal. 33

Comment: Can you downgrading `firebase-admin to 9.8.0`&`firebase-functions to 3.22.0` and try?

Answer (score 3):

Try running `npm outdated` to make sure that you don't have an outdated package.

I had a similar issue with those versions :

```
Package                  Current   Wanted  Latest  Location                              Depended by
tslint                    5.20.1   5.20.1   6.1.3  node_modules/tslint                   functions
typescript                3.9.10   3.9.10   4.9.4  node_modules/typescript               functions
```

Upgrading them to their latest had solved it for me.